# Why my weights are transposed when load to a new PyTorch model

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm using PyTorch 2.0.0 to create a neural network. My model structure is

```
>>> torch_model
TorchModel(
  (dropout): Dropout(p=0, inplace=False)
  (base): Sequential(
    (0): Flatten(start_dim=1, end_dim=-1)
    (1): Linear(in_features=18018, out_features=1024, bias=True)
    (2): ReLU()
    (3): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=512, bias=True)
    (4): ReLU()
  )
```

I saved trained weights by

```
def save_blocks(self, path):
        inters_dir = self.__pthjoin(path, 'inters')
        integs_dir = self.__pthjoin(path, 'integs')
        outputs_dir = self.__pthjoin(path, 'outputs')
        for dir in [path, inters_dir, integs_dir, outputs_dir]:
            if not os.path.isdir(dir):
                os.mkdir(dir)
        torch.save(self.base.state_dict(), self.__pthjoin(path, 'base'))
```

When I tried to restore my model through

```
def __restore_from(self, path):
        base_dir = self.__pthjoin(path, 'base')
        self.base = self.init_base_block(num_features=len(self.statistics))
        self.base.load_state_dict(torch.load(base_dir))
```

It occurred that

```
RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for Sequential:
        size mismatch for 1.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([18018, 1024]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([1024, 18018]).
        size mismatch for 3.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([1024, 512]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([512, 1024]).
```

I attempt to same the whole model using

```
torch.save(torch_model, path)
```

and it works fine. But I just want to know why my weights are transposed using state dict.

Comment: But how did you load? did you do this: model.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH))?

Comment: Yes, my __restore_from function is:
```
def __restore_from(self, path):
        base_dir = self.__pthjoin(path, 'base')
        self.base = self.init_base_block(num_features=len(self.statistics))
        self.base.load_state_dict(torch.load(base_dir))
```

Comment: What is init_base_block?

Comment: init_base_block is a function to initialize my neural network, the code of this function is:
```
def init_base_block(self, num_features):
        block = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Flatten(),
            nn.Linear(num_features, 2**10),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(2**10, 2**9),
            nn.ReLU()
        )
        block.apply(relu_init)
        return block
```

Answer (score 0):

Very strange, I have torch 2.0.0 and I run this and no error:

```
import torch.nn as nn
import torch

class SimpleModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.fc = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(in_features=18018, out_features=1024, bias=True),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=512, bias=True)
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.fc(x)
        return x

model = SimpleModel()
torch.save(model.state_dict(), "my_model.pt") #save

#now to load
model = SimpleModel()
model.load_state_dict(torch.load("my_model.pt"))
```

Everything ok, no error. Just compare my code with yours. Maybe you have some error in creating the model class.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seems like the error from converting model from keras to PyTorch. I have solved it and post my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. The problem is that this model is a PyTorch model converted from Keras. I copy the Keras model's weight by

```
torch_model.base[1].weight.data = torch.from_numpy(keras_model.base.get_weights()[0]).float()
    torch_model.base[1].bias.data = torch.from_numpy(keras_model.base.get_weights()[1]).float()
    torch_model.base[3].weight.data = torch.from_numpy(keras_model.base.get_weights()[2]).float()
    torch_model.base[3].bias.data = torch.from_numpy(keras_model.base.get_weights()[3]).float()
```

But the attribute 'weight' in PyTorch model is a matrix with shape (output_size, input_size). I edited my code to

```
torch_model.base[1].weight.data = torch.from_numpy(keras_model.base.get_weights()[0]).float().T
    torch_model.base[1].bias.data = torch.from_numpy(keras_model.base.get_weights()[1]).float()
    torch_model.base[3].weight.data = torch.from_numpy(keras_model.base.get_weights()[2]).float().T
    torch_model.base[3].bias.data = torch.from_numpy(keras_model.base.get_weights()[3]).float()
```

and everything works fine.